# android emulator is start but window show blank screen

Tags: android, emulation

WARN/WindowManager(61): No focus window, dropping: KeyEvent{action=0 code=82 repeat=0 meta=0 scancode=229 mFlags=8}

Answer (score 2):

That seams a problem of 1.6

Upgrade to 2.1 and shall disappear.

Comment: i am developing in android 2.1 only

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with a blank black screen after the emulator was started by Titanium and none of the emulator buttons such as Menu or Home did anything.

To fix it I entered the following commands from the sdk / tools directory:

```
android list avd
```

This listed the emulator images.  In my case it listed two:

```
Available Android Virtual Devices:
    Name: titanium_3_WVGA854
    Path: C:\Users\xxx\.android\avd\titanium_3_WVGA854.avd
  Target: Android 1.6 (API level 4)
    Skin: WVGA854
  Sdcard: C:\Users\xxx\.titanium\android.sdcard
---------
    Name: titanium_8_WVGA854
    Path: C:\Users\xxx\.android\avd\titanium_8_WVGA854.avd
  Target: Google APIs (Google Inc.)
          Based on Android 2.2 (API level 8)
    Skin: WVGA854
  Sdcard: C:\Users\xxx\.titanium\android.sdcard
```

In my case I wanted the Android 2.2 API so I entered

```
emulator @titanium_8_wvga854
```

Answer (score 0):

windows xp
Running Android emulator version 10.0 (build_id OPENMASTER-104271)

Kill the emulator which cause a dumprep.exe which I killed too.

You just need to resave the AVD configuration. Perhaps something got corrupted

In eclipse > Android SDK and AVD Manager, select your AVD Name and click Edit ...

Click Edit AVD ( resaves your settings )

select your AVD Name and Click Start...

Answer (score 0):

its only a problem of computer memory, sometimes when we build again and again by eclipse or other IDE, it consumes memory (don't know why maybe because of leaks) and it memory is user 90% , so that sometimes it creates problem for emulator launching and takes a lot of time to get launched.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling Host GPU in the settings for the AVD worked for me. This was a problem for me with 2.3, but not 5.0.